# how to print image by printer [Django]

Tags: python, django, printing

I want to print only selected images by printer at server side.

the language is python. framework is django.

could you give me idea?

best regards.

Comment: Your server side has a printer ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to interface the Django WebApp with the OS. To do this, you will have to wrap shell commands in python code.

For example, if you have an Ubuntu sytem running the Django Webapp, you might write the following piece of code somewhere in your `views.py` function:

```
import subprocess
return_code = subprocess.call("lpr /path-to-file-to-print", shell=True)
```

Where lpr is the default shell command to print items. The exact commands might differ from OS to OS, but the underlying concept remains the same.